# Lower and upper limits of deterministic node in JAGS

Tags: jags

I'm trying to truncate a deterministic node, `theta.t`, to ensure its values lie between 0 and 1. 
I've tried to solve the issue by employing `T(0,1)` at the end of line 6, but this doesn't work, and I'm not sure how to use `~ dinterval()` to address this particular problem.

I'm using JAGS 3.3.0 and R 3.0.2.

Here's my code:

```
model {
  # PRIORS
  alpha ~ dunif(0,1)
  beta ~ dunif(0,1)
  # Deterministic Node
  for(j in 1:n.intervals) {
    theta.t[j] <- exp(-alpha * retention.intervals[j]) + beta
  }
  # DATA
  for(i in 1:n.participants) {
    for(j in 1:n.intervals) {
      k[i, j] ~ dbin(theta.t[j], 18)
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Chapter 7 of the [JAGS manual](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mcmc-jags/files/Manuals/3.x/) indicates that it is impossible to truncate or censor deterministic nodes. You can only perform truncation and censoring on stochastic nodes.

The only way you have is to change your priors.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `min` and `max` to achieve this. For example, to constrain `theta[j]` such that it lies between 0 and 1:

```
theta.t[j] <- max(0, min(1, exp(-alpha * retention.intervals[j]) + beta))
```

Comment: This approach does not work for me. I still get estimated values greater than or less than the constraints